# Regarding SLUG in MVC

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, routes

Working on a MVC Application that basically is a front end database of my City's listings/Directory.

Registered Listings are called like the following:

```
something.com/Listings/View/{some-guid}
```

Is it possible to display in this format:

```
something.com/{slug version of the destination name}
```

or

```
something.com/kfc-arabia
```

This would be of great ease to share the links with clients, also SEO Friendly.

Comment: is this ASP.net MVC? What framework are you using?

Comment: Yes ASP.net . Framework of 4.5 @JackM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be difficult to match your slug at the root of your application as this would not allow for other routes in your application.  However if you can achieve something like what you want by doing the following

```
something.com/directory/{slug}
```

With this you would just need a simply rule to match this to a suitable action that takes your slug as a parameter.

e.g.

```
context.MapRoute("Listings_by_slug", 
                 "directory/{slug}", 
                  new { controller = "Listings", 
                  action = "ViewBySlug" });
```

and your action would be something like this

```
 public ActionResult ViewBySlug(string slug){
      var listingGuid = _service.GetGuidFromSlug(slug);
      return RedirectToAction("View", "Listing", new { id = listingGuid);
}
```

UPDATE

If you really want that then you could have a route like

```
context.MapRoute("Listings_by_slug", 
                 "{slug}", 
                  new { controller = "Listings", 
                  action = "ViewBySlug" });
```

You'd want to put this after other routes you need as this route matches anything to your application.  In effect it should be your last declared route.  Also you could not have a controlller with the same name as a slug

Comment: Thanks , but i really would want it to be something.com/{slug} and i want this slug thingy not to be autogenerated , but chosen while creating a details page by client and saved into the database , like username concept in all social media sites...Possible ?? @dove

Comment: @MukeshMurugan, Can you please take a moment and consider these: What is a Controller(in your context), What are the views(in your context) and think about the way you are going to do your routing. From this abstracted question you will have a million abstracted answers. Also if you can/want, share the code

Comment: @MukeshMurugan it is possible, I've updated the answer

Comment: Thanks @dove <3 Managed to do it....But found a clash with other controllers....Even if i go to something.com/Index , the mapping thinks that Index is a slug and tries to fetch from the Listings xontroller...Fixed it by adding constraints..Thanks..

Comment: if you put the other routes above the slug route it should still allow for /index etc as that would be matched first